# React for futures

Tags: scala, actor, future

I am trying to use a divide-and-conquer (aka fork/join) approach for a number crunching problem. Here is the code:

```
import scala.actors.Futures.future

private def compute( input: Input ):Result = {
  if( pairs.size < SIZE_LIMIT ) {
    computeSequential()
  } else {
    val (input1,input2) = input.split
    val f1 = future( compute(input1) )
    val f2 = future( compute(input2) )
    val result1 = f1()
    val result2 = f2()
    merge(result1,result2)
  }
}
```

It runs (with a nice speed-up) but the the future apply method seems to block a thread and the thread pool increases tremendously. And when too many threads are created, the computations is stucked.

Is there a kind of *react* method for futures which releases the thread ? Or any other way to achieve that behavior ?

**EDIT:** I am using scala 2.8.0.final

Comment: I've run into exactly the same issue myself--and haven't had any luck in solving it aside from switching to using a worker/supervisor model with reactors.  Hopefully someone else will have suggestions that will recover the ease of use of futures!  I think I dimly recall that switching the thread scheduler to an older version helped in at least one case...?

Comment: I'm not sure, which version of Scala're you using, but according to the source code of 2.8.0.final, call to Futures:future creates an actor (that 'reacts') and immediately returns it to the calling thread: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src//actors/scala/actors/Future.scala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't claim (apply) your `Future`s, since this forces them to block and wait for an answer; as you've seen this can lead to deadlocks. Instead, use them monadically to tell them what to do when they complete. Instead of:

```
val result1 = f1()
val result2 = f2()
merge(result1,result2)
```

Try this:

```
for {
  result1 <- f1
  result2 <- f2
} yield merge(result1, result2)
```

The result of this will be a `Responder[Result]` (essentially a `Future[Result]`) containing the merged results; you can do something effectful with this final value using `respond()` or `foreach()`, or you can `map()` or `flatMap()` it to another `Responder[T]`. No blocking necessary, just keep scheduling computations for the future!

### Edit 1:

Ok, the signature of the `compute` function is going to have to change to `Responder[Result]` now, so how does that affect the recursive calls? Let's try this:

```
private def compute( input: Input ):Responder[Result] = {
  if( pairs.size < SIZE_LIMIT ) {
    future(computeSequential())
  } else {
    val (input1,input2) = input.split
    for {
      result1 <- compute(input1)
      result2 <- compute(input2)
    } yield merge(result1, result2)
  }
}
```

Now you no longer need to wrap the calls to `compute` with `future(...)` because they're already returning `Responder` (a superclass of `Future`).

### Edit 2:

One upshot of using this continuation-passing style is that your top-level code--whatever calls `compute` originally--doesn't block at all any more. If it's being called from `main()`, and that's all the program does, this will be a problem, because now it will just spawn a bunch of futures and then immediately shut down, having finished everything it was told to do. What you need to do is `block` on all these futures, but only once, at the top level, and only on the results of *all* the computations, not any intermediate ones.

Unfortunately, this `Responder` thing that's being returned by `compute()` no longer has a blocking `apply()` method like the `Future` did. I'm not sure why flatMapping `Future`s produces a generic `Responder` instead of a `Future`; this seems like an API mistake. But in any case, you should be able to make your own:

```
def claim[A](r:Responder[A]):A = {
  import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue
  import scala.actors.Actor.actor

  val q = new ArrayBlockingQueue[A](1)
  // uses of 'respond' need to be wrapped in an actor or future block
  actor { r.respond(a => q.put(a)) } 
  return q.take
}
```

So now you can create a blocking call to compute in your `main` method like so:

```
val finalResult = claim(compute(input))
```

Comment: I don't think this helps.  This just pushes back the problem another level; now it'll deadlock in the merges--well, it might, depending on how you rewrite merge to work with `Responder`s.

Comment: Why do you say that? Keep in mind that the merge is happening in a new thread that's only spawned after `f1` and `f2` are both finished computing.

Comment: the merge is not operating on `Responders`, it's operating on `Result` values. Its code doesn't need to change at all.

Comment: @pelotom - Maybe I'm not understanding what you envision happens inside "merge".  The code you wrote doesn't compile for me with a trivial example (where the OP's code does compile, with appropriate additions).

Comment: @Rex, I have no idea what `merge` does; it's a black box to me :) All I know is its signature, `(Result, Result) => Result` is unchanged, and if it worked before it will still work...

Comment: @Rex I never got the OP's code to compile since there's so much missing, but this should compile as a trivial example of monadic futures: `for (i <- future(5); j <- future(6)) yield (i + j)`

Comment: @pelotom - But now compute's return type is Responder[Result].  And those are getting wrapped into futures in the recursive call.  So either recursion seems to be broken, or we don't seem to have gotten anywhere.

Comment: @Rex Kerr - You're right, the return type has to change, which means the recursion needs to be modified. See my edit.

Comment: I tried your approach (BEFORE THE EDIT). It compiles fine but when it runs, it crashes instantaneously without any stacktrace. I just get a 'scala.actors.SuspendActorControl' one line eon console and a non zero return code...

Comment: @pelotom - It crashes still but at least I have a stack trace. `scala.actors.ActorProxy@641a034d: caught java.lang.InterruptedException`

Comment: @paradigmatic: without seeing your code I can't be sure, but I would hazard a guess that you're shutting down prematurely now since all your code has gone future-y. See my second edit.

Comment: @pelotom - Still crashing with the second edit. BTW merge() is a pure function, both args, result and all created objects are immutable and not shared among different futures/threads. The interrupted exception is reported to originate from `scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread`.

Comment: @paradigmatic: if you want to make a pastee with a self-contained testcase which reproduces the problem, I'll take a look at it...

Comment: @pelotom - I did a minimal crashing toy example (producing sorted list of random ints). The culprit seems to be the claim method. Thanks to have a look: https://gist.github.com/4d6667280072a47cc9df

Comment: @paradigmatic: Ok, I edited `claim()` above, please try it out. There were 2 problems: I shouldn't have been using a SynchronousQueue (that was causing the program to hang) and `respond`/`foreach` blocks need to be wrapped in an `actor` or `future` to avoid the exceptions you were seeing. Those exceptions are used by actors for control flow, and certain actor functions depend on these mechanisms to work, `respond` being one of them.

Comment: @paradigmatic: time to crack out that profiler... but I'm afraid I've done all I can for you

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try to figure out the loss of speed-up, and I'll try also the jsr166y.

Comment: You might also try doing this with the monadic futures (called promises) provided by scalaz (http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/). I've had success with those, whereas my knowledge of scala's actor futures is mostly theoretical. They give you more control over the parallelization strategy used (e.g. the kind of threadpool used).